# "It (a course) was supposed to teach us to think in a certain way." Is the preposition required?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say that it (a course) was supposed to teach us to think **in** a certain way. Will the sentence still be grammatically correct if I omit the bold **in** and will it still convey the same meaning? To me the sentence, "It was supposed to teach us to think a certain way." seems correct and to be conveying the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both variants are [equally common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=think%20a%20certain%20way%2C%20think%20in%20a%20certain%20way&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthink%20a%20certain%20way%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthink%20in%20a%20certain%20way%3B%2Cc0), although it seems that *think **in** a certain way* manages to keep the upper hand, being the complete formal expression. Removing ***in*** does not alter the meaning, and this is why probably many say *think a certain way* (it is less formal than the complete expression though).

The same issue can be raised with ***doing something (in) the right way***.

Some say that there are specific verbs, like ***vote*** for example, who can legitimately be used without ***in*** to avoid ambiguity.

> Electioneering—the effort parties and others make to persuade electors ***to vote a particular way*** *[with one candidate or another - "in a particular way" could be misunderstood as "by post" or "in person"]*. ([Oxford reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjh9viJ_PHxAhUDRUEAHVetC8MQFjAFegQIDBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.oxfordreference.com%2Fview%2F10.1093%2Foi%2Fauthority.20110803095745719%3Frskey%3DNMXeYV%26result%3D19&usg=AOvVaw2fdL-_-sr9bRsj-RaTqi5q))